# Vertical centering with line-height

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

```
<div style="line-height:100px; height:100px;">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">test</span>
</div>
```

Only when `vertical-align:middle` is specified in the span, the above html produces different result from the below.

```
<div style="height:100px;">
    <span style="line-height:100px; vertical-align:middle;">test</span>
</div>
```

It's placed down by 1px on chrome and firefox, and by 2px on ie8.

Why is it different?

Comment: My guess would be that different browsers interpret line-height differently. Of course I could be wrong here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is div tag's default `border-width` set it `0px` and then see the change.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between the SPAN and DIV elements is that SPAN doesn’t do any formatting of it’s own. The DIV element includes a paragraph break. The SPAN element simply tells the browser to apply the style rules to whatever is within the SPAN.

And I'm thinking that because of the little bit of formatting div does could be the difference.

Comment: My question is why the rendering is different when `line-height` is applied to the `div` from when it's applied to the `span`. It's not specific to IE. It's 1px difference on chrome and firefox, and 2px difference on ie8.

Comment: Oh oh sorry I misunderstood the question. Please disregard. But to somewhat answer your question I've edited my question